# How to load multiple schemas into a Rails engine or app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rubygems, rake, rails-engines

Seeking to move all my shared models to an engine which can be included in each of my micro apps.

This engine should provide a model layer to all our legacy data, including:

- Model files
- Schema files
- Migrations (we're following [Pivotal Labs' pattern](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines), this isn't the issue)

Model files are being patched in automatically, that's fine.

Schema files are being monkey-patched in using [Nikolay Strum's db.rake](http://blog.nistu.de/2012/03/25/multi-database-setup-with-rails-and-rspec):

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :schema do
    # desc 'Dump additional database schema'
    task :dump => [:environment, :load_config] do
      filename = "#{Rails.root}/db/foo_schema.rb"
      File.open(filename, 'w:utf-8') do |file|
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("foo_#{Rails.env}")
        ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file)
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :test do
    # desc 'Purge and load foo_test schema'
    task :load_schema do
      # like db:test:purge
      abcs = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.recreate_database(abcs['foo_test']['database'], mysql_creation_options(abcs['foo_test']))
      # like db:test:load_schema
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection('foo_test')
      ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
      load("#{Rails.root}/db/foo_schema.rb")
    end
  end
end
```

We need `rake db:create` and `rake db:schema:load` to work,

The `db.rake` patches only affect `db:schema:dump` and `db:test:load_schema` (part of tests_prepare, I assume). I've attempted to patch them into `db:schema:load` using:

```
namespace :db do

  # Helpers
  def mysql_creation_options(config)
    @charset   = ENV['CHARSET']   || 'utf8'
    @collation = ENV['COLLATION'] || 'utf8_unicode_ci'
    {:charset => (config['charset'] || @charset), :collation => (config['collation'] || @collation)}
  end

  def load_schema(schema_name)
    abcs = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.recreate_database(abcs[schema_name+'_test']['database'], mysql_creation_options(abcs[schema_name+'_test']))
    # like db:test:load_schema
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(schema_name+'_test')
    ActiveRecord::Schema.verbose = false
    load("#{Rails.root}/db/#{schema_name}_schema.rb")
  end

  namespace :schema do
    # desc 'Dump additional database schema'
    task :dump => [:environment, :load_config] do
      dump_schema = -> (schema_name) {
        filename = "#{Rails.root}/db/#{schema_name}_schema.rb"
        File.open(filename, 'w:utf-8') do |file|
          ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection("#{schema_name}_#{Rails.env}")
          ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file)
        end
      }

      dump_schema.call('kiddom')
      dump_schema.call('kiddom_warehouse')
    end

    # When loading from schema, load these files, too
    task :load => [:environment, :load_config] do
      load_schema('kiddom')
      load_schema('kiddom_warehouse')
    end
  end

  namespace :test do
    # desc 'Purge and load foo_test schema'
    task :load_schema do
      load_schema('kiddom')
      load_schema('kiddom_warehouse')
    end
  end
end
```

But this gives me the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'recreate_database' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLite3Adapter:0x007feb6bb43558>`. Apparently, this only works on Oracle-type databases?

What are the Rails commands for the underlying `DROP` and `CREATE DATABASE` sql I'm trying to affect for the extra `schema.rb`'s?

Comment: I worked with an engine containing models once. We only shared the models and the migrations and that worked fine. The `schema.rb` we kept individually for each app; the engine provided none. This makes sense imho since the database belongs to an app, not to an engine. HTH

Comment: Thx Raffael! In most cases, you're exactly right: The engine adds new model code, or extends existing models, and it makes sense to let the schema.rb live in the app. In our case, however, the engine represents models that live in an entirely different database - so we need to have a different schema file for these models (right?)

Comment: I see. I never worked with multiple databases, although I was always curious as how to do this. Apparently you can use different databases on a per-model-class basis. It gets a bit trickyer if you need to run migrations on the additional databases, too; see http://excid3.com/blog/rails-activerecord-multiple-databases-and-migrations/

Comment: Have you tried using `drop` and `create` method in `ActiveRecord::Tasks`? : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Tasks/DatabaseTasks.html#method-i-drop

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQLite as your database engine. Hope that is what you want to do.

Since you are creating SQLite Database , things differ a bit from other database adapters like MySQLAdpter or Postgress.

In case of MySQL, database has to be created prior to establish a connection by spending "CREATE DATABASE ... "  SQL commands. So you must create the database before establishing connection.

But in case of SQLite, since the database reside in a file and one file can contain only one database, there is no separate step to create database. An attempt to establishing a connection to the database itself will cause the database file to be created.

Hence create_database method won't work when using SQLiteAdapter. You can simply remove that line from your code.

You may have a look at the source code for the Rake task db:create

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake

Also, the source code for 'create' method in SQLiteDatabaseTasks. As you can see, it simply calls the establish_connection method

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f47b4236e089b07cb683ee9b7ff8b06111a0ec10/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake